# How do I filter some Stack Exchange sites out of the feed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

How can I set a filter so that some Stack Exchange sites will never contribute to the hot network questions or feed that I see?

For example, while I may occasionally contribute to grammar discussions for English, I have never participated in the Stack Exchange site for Japanese and am not losing out on any serendipitous discoveries by not reading questions about fine points of a language I cannot speak or read.

And yet there is a question tagged "grammar" from the Japanese stack in my feed right now.

Similarly I have no interest in Puzzling Code Golf even though I have contributed to several technical subs and even to coding threads.

(I thought I had seen this question before, but a few combinations of search terms did not find it.)